# Is read-only BIOS flashable?

Tags: bios, linux-mint, chromebook

I would like to replace Chrome OS with Linux Mint on Acer Chromebook. Problem is it has a read-only BIOS (thanks...!). Would it be possible/feasible to flash this and make it into an read-write BIOS and then change the OS ? (I am newbie-ish, please forgive if this is obviously not possible)

Comment: If it's actually read-only; no; then it cannot be changed.  It also means it cannot be updated so it's unlikely read-only

Comment: `Is read-only BIOS flashable?` Common sense would say no.

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed install Linux on a Chromebook.  The article [here](http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/764181-how-to-install-linux-on-an-acer-c720-chromebook) shows how to install Ubuntu or Bodhi, but the principles would apply to Mint as well.  You should also study the articles & blogs [here](http://chromebooklinux.blogspot.com/) and [here](http://www.chromestory.com/2013/02/how-to-install-linuxmint-on-your-chromebook-pixel/#more-8048), which talk a bit about the risks and potentials.

It does take a bit of work and messing around with settings, but it's doable.  And you don't need to mess with the BIOS at all.